# Drupal 7 creating list from comma separated field in Rules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-rules

I am trying to create a list of nodes by using the value of a submitted field with comma separated values. I want each value to be used a s a list item. How can I convert the comma separated list into individual list items?

Answer (score 0):

This module https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_data_transforms solves the issue. It allows you to explode a comma delimitated string into a list.